# Error in visual studio 2015 which goes away in 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intel-media-sdk

I am running the following code on my Windows10 machine with API version 1.19 of Intel Media SDK.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"mfxvideo++.h"

void main() {
    printf("this is a new program using intel media sdk");

    mfxSession SWsess;
    mfxVersion SWver = {0,1}, ver;
    mfxStatus sts;

    sts = MFXInit(MFX_IMPL_SOFTWARE, &SWver, &SWsess);

    if (MFX_ERR_NONE == sts) {
        MFXQueryVersion(SWsess, &ver);
        printf("Implementation version: %d.%d and API version: %d.%d", SWver.Major, SWver.Minor, ver.Major, ver.Minor);
    }

    MFXClose(SWsess);

    getchar();
}
```

I made the project in Visual Studio 2015 but received following errors

Severity    Error Code
Description
Project
File path
Program Line

**The errors have been written in above format.**

```
Error LNK1120
2 unresolved externals
ScreenCapture
~\Visual Studio\ScreenCapture\x64\Debug\ScreenCapture.exe
1

Error LNK2019
unresolved external symbol __imp_printf referenced in function main
ScreenCapture
~\Visual Studio\ScreenCapture\ScreenCapture\main.obj
1

Error LNK2019
unresolved external symbol swscanf_s referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl MFX::MFXPluginsInFS::ParseKVPair(wchar_t *,wchar_t *,class MFX::PluginDescriptionRecord &)" (?ParseKVPair@MFXPluginsInFS@MFX@@AEAA_NPEA_W0AEAVPluginDescriptionRecord@2@@Z)
ScreenCapture
~\Visual Studio\ScreenCapture\ScreenCapture\libmfx.lib(mfx_plugin_hive.obj)
1

Warning LNK4098
defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
ScreenCapture
~\Visual Studio\ScreenCapture\ScreenCapture\LINK
1
```

However, in Visual Studio 2012 the aforementioned code runs fine. **Please advise what should I do to upgrade my project to Visual Studio 2015?**

I faced LNK2019 in Visual Studio 2017RC ([Refer here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1163428/Error-LNK-using-visual-studio-RC)) so I rolled back to Visual Studio 2015 and 2012. Solutions available for the errors on this or other forums have not worked for me until now. For warning LNK4098, I couldn't conclude which libraries to ignore.

Comment: ***defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library*** Means you have a CRT conflict. Make sure that you are using a version of the SDK that is compatible with your compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2015 and VS 2017 use the [Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) which is not binary or link compatible with older Visual Studio CRT implementations. Generally speaking, CRTs are not compatible between major version of the compiler.

IOW: that version of Intel Media SDK doesn't support VS 2015.